# Get Polygon or IGeometry from Envelope in ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, geometry

I would like to create a Polygon Feature from the geometry of an IEnvelope in C# ArcObjects SDK 10. Is there an easy way how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a polygon from an envelope is to cast a new [Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000045r000000) instance to [ISegmentCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000035r000000) and call the [ISegmentCollection.SetRectangle](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000036q000000) method, passing the envelope as its argument.